# Array retornando erro "Can't use function return value in write context in"

Tags: php, array

Estou criando um `array` mas esta me retornando o erro:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in C:\xampp\htdocs\cadastro_insert.php on line 54:

Aonde estou errando???

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6); --> tambem tentei:  $genero = array(6);
$x = 0;

if ($genero01 != "") {
$x++;
$array($x) = $genero01;
}

if ($genero02 != "") {
$x++;
$array($x) = $genero02;
}
```

...

Comment: Substitua `$array($x)` por `$array[$x]`

Comment: Deu certo roberto. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

#### Motivo

Conforme já dito, o erro estava ao chamar o array, onde está usando *parênteses* ao invés de *colchetes*:

```
$array($x) = $genero01;

$array($x) = $genero02;
```

---

#### Corrigindo

```
if ($genero01 != "") {
  $x++;
  $array[$x] = $genero01;
}

if ($genero02 != "") {
  $x++;
  $array[$x] = $genero02;
}
```